# Action Server timeout across systems

Tags: ros, action-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having trouble with actionlib.SimpleActionClient wait_for_server timing out when the client and server are on different systems and I could use help understanding why.  In this case, roscore and the action server is running on a Raspberry Pi and the client is running on an Ubuntu VM.  Both are running Indigo.  I have a simple example that runs fine when the client and server run on the same computer (the Raspberry Pi).  However when I run roscore and the action server on the Raspberry Pi and I run these commands on the Ubuntu client side:

- rosnode list correctly lists the server node
- rostopic list correctly lists the topics
- rosnode ping ping_action_server shows repeated successful pings of about 20 msecs

However, when I run the following client code it fails to connect...

```
import sys
import rospy
import actionlib

from inmoov.msg import PingAction, PingGoal, PingResult

def onShutdown():
    rospy.loginfo("Shutting down")

try:  
    rospy.init_node('ping_client', log_level=rospy.DEBUG)
    rospy.on_shutdown(onShutdown)
    client = actionlib.SimpleActionClient('ping', PingAction)
    rospy.loginfo("Waiting for ping action server...")
    finished = client.wait_for_server(timeout = rospy.Duration(10.0))
    if(finished is False): 
        rospy.logerr("Ping action server timed out")
    else:
        rospy.loginfo("Ping action server found")
    
except:
    print("An exception was encountered")
    e = sys.exc_info()[0]
    print str(e)
```

The output is:

```
[DEBUG] [WallTime: 1473631183.986657] init_node, name[/ping_client], pid[7947]
[DEBUG] [WallTime: 1473631183.987061] binding to 0.0.0.0 0
[DEBUG] [WallTime: 1473631183.987256] bound to 0.0.0.0 35061
[DEBUG] [WallTime: 1473631183.987703] ... service URL is rosrpc://raspberrypi:35061
[DEBUG] [WallTime: 1473631183.987884] [/ping_client/get_loggers]: new Service instance
[DEBUG] [WallTime: 1473631184.003141] ... service URL is rosrpc://raspberrypi:35061
[DEBUG] [WallTime: 1473631184.003397] [/ping_client/set_logger_level]: new Service instance
[INFO] [WallTime: 1473631184.130352] Waiting for ping action server...
[DEBUG] [WallTime: 1473631184.131371] connecting to raspberrypi 52197
[DEBUG] [WallTime: 1473631184.131768] connecting to raspberrypi 52197
[DEBUG] [WallTime: 1473631184.152471] connecting to raspberrypi 52197
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1473631194.139802] Ping action server timed out
[INFO] [WallTime: 1473631194.140166] Shutting down
[DEBUG] [WallTime: 1473631194.192350] connecting to raspberrypi 52197
[DEBUG] [WallTime: 1473631194.193241] connecting to raspberrypi 52197
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.  If it matters, I have a ROS publisher that runs on the Ubuntu VM and a ROS Subscriber on the Raspberry Pi that successfully receives the published messages.  The Raspberry Pi has a static IP and the Ubuntu VM has an entry in /etc/hosts to map the static IP to the host name "raspberrypi".

Here are the Ubuntu environment settings:

```
mike@badmonkey:~$ printenv | grep ROS
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/mike/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://raspberrypi:11311
ROS_HOSTNAME=raspberrypi
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/mike/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp
ROS_DISTRO=indigo
ROS_LANG_DISABLE=genlisp
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/indigo/etc/ros
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243537/action-server-timeout-across-systems/) by [anonymous27962](https://answers.ros.org/users/27962/anonymous27962/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2016-09-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-09-11**:
Your hostname is `badmonkey` but your `ROS_HOSTNAME` is `raspberrypi`. Can you ping a node that is running on your Ubuntu machine from your raspberry pi?

**Comment by [anonymous27962](https://answers.ros.org/users/27962/anonymous27962/) on 2016-09-12**:
No, rosnode list includes the node, but I get this...

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ rosnode ping leap_motion_publisher
rosnode: node is [/leap_motion_publisher]
pinging /leap_motion_publisher with a timeout of 3.0s
ERROR: connection refused to [http://raspberrypi:45057/]
```

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-09-12**:
Your hostname is `badmonkey` but your ROS_HOSTNAME is `raspberrypi`, so any nodes running on your Ubuntu machine are advertising the wrong host name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @ahendrix pointed out in the question comments, I was confused about ROS_HOSTNAME.  I had assumed that was the hostname of the node running roscore.  When I changed the ROS_HOSTNAME to properly reflect the hostname of the Ubuntu VM to be badmonkey instead of raspberrypi, the problem was resolved.

Thank you for your help!

---

Originally posted by [anonymous27962](https://answers.ros.org/users/27962/anonymous27962/) with karma: 76 on 2016-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1